# I can't create custom model of Visual Recognition in my Watson Studio environment

Tags: watson, visual-recognition, watson-studio

When I tried to create the custom model of Visual recognition in Watson Studio environment, I always received the following error message.

```
Preparing Watson Studio
Failed to get resource group.
```

I also attached error message as the image at that time.

[image: the error message of watson studio]

In addition, when I tried to create the new project with something like Jupyter notebooks, I encountered the same error.

I don't know why, but I think my Watson Studio might not be connected to the cloud object storage properly. This is for a hands-on seminar of VR for my customers in my environment.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Is this a paid version? If so open a support ticket.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my impolite way. My version is not paid but Lite. So, I hope I could get something like lints on a volunteer basis.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting error, I've not seen this before. I would recommend checking the region you have deployed Watson Studio to in your [IBM Cloud Dashboard](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps) matches the URL of the Watson Studio instance you are working in. This will either be in [US South](https://dataplatform.ibm.com) or [United Kingdom](https://eu-gb.dataplatform.ibm.com).

Comment: Thank you for replying. The region I have deployed is US South, and the url of the instance I'm working in is also US South.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps that are needed to utilize Visual Recognition through Watson Studio.  First both the Watson Studio and Visual Recognition services need to be added to your IBM Cloud account.  The error message you are encountering indicates there may be an issue with the project.  This may be an issue with the Cloud Object Storage as you mentioned.  There could be two types of object storage in your projects Cloud Object Storage and Swift API Object Storage.  The older Swift API Object Storage will not work with Visual Recognition which is a new service.  You can verify that you have the Cloud Object Storage and not the older swift Object Storage by logging into your IBM Cloud Account.  You may also be able to see buckets with names similar to the projects in the Object Storage.  If the Cloud Object Storage is accessible and you can create a project, you should see the Object Storage under the Settings Tab.  You should also see blue boxes with white checkmarks showing the available services, one should be Visual Recognition.  If you have already added the service, it will be under the Associated services tab.  If the Object Storage is not accessible through IBM Cloud then you should be able to open a support ticket even on the lite plan.  If the Object Storage is accessible and Watson Studio returns the error on a freshly created project you may also wish to open a ticket.  As the service is currently accessible the issue would be specific to your account and additional information may be needed.

Comment: Welcome to [Stackoverflow.com](https://$SITEURL$/tour) Please use formatting tools within post form to make your post more readable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had the Cloud Object Storage, but once I deleted this, and now I try to create the new project from scratch. When I tried to  create COS during the process of creating the new project, I encountered the permission error.

Comment: The error message is as follows.

------------<error message>---------------
You do not have permissions to create services in this account. Contact your account owner for access.
----------------------------------------------------
This is my current situation. I've opened the ticket. Anyway, I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have resolved your issue now. I got the same issue for object storage, I have resolved it by deleting the service and project associated with that and then creating new one. Thats it!

Comment: Thank you for your information. Now, The above issue have been fixed. I appreciate your kindly following.